# How to draw text above graph tree lines?

Tags: tikz-trees

I want to draw a tree that's similar to the last one (except for the slashed nodes) but I can't get the text above the lines right
[image: Text]

I'm at

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](a){$1,0$}
  child{node[circle,draw, auto=left]{$0,6$} 
   child {node[circle,draw](c){$0,3$}
    child {node[circle,draw](d){$0,1$}}
    child {node[circle,draw](e){$0,2$}}
   }
   child {node[circle,draw](f){$0,3$}}
  }
  child{
    node[circle,draw](g){$0,4$}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and I already tried with `\path [line] (a) -- node [text width=0.5cm,above] {0} (b);`  but it was all jumbled

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the desired behavior, you can use the `edge from parent` element of the `tikz` `trees` library which allows you to link to nodes with a node placed on it.

This would lead for example to:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{line} = [draw]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,draw](a){$1,0$}
    child{%
        node[circle,draw, auto=left]{$0,6$}
        child {%
            node[circle,draw](c){$0,3$}
            child {%
                node[circle,draw](d){$0,1$}
                edge from parent
                    node [above left] {$0$}
            }
            child {%
                node[circle,draw](e){$0,2$}
                edge from parent
                    node [above right] {$1$}
            }
            edge from parent
                node [above left] {$0$}
        }
    child {%
        node[circle,draw](f){$0,3$}
        edge from parent
            node [above right] {$1$}
    }
    edge from parent
        node[above left] {$0$}
    }
    child{%
        node[circle,draw](g){$0,4$}
        edge from parent
            node [above right] {$1$}
    };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]

Be careful to put the `edge from parent` element after all the `child`s of one `node`, else, your tree will be broken.